# How to write a formula to rank and tie-breaks for decisions of vacation priority

Tags: excel, math, data-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have a been tasked to design a process to rank and tie-break vacation plans of a given crew. There is a set of rules to be respected and I need to make a formula to put in Excel so we can see the rank of members to choose vacation dates over other.

The set of rules are the following:

1. The compliance of training (0-100%)? In this case the higher the better to rank up.
2. How long ago this individual took vacations (in days)? In this case he ranks up if vacation were longer.
3. How many days to expire his next vacation (in days)? This uses a formula Today-Expiring date, the closer to today the better, but in this case we have a "if case": if the vacation is less than 90 days his chances will increase to make sure he goes to the top.
4. Did the individual was on license in the last 12 months (Boolean)? If he took the license, then he rank down, if not he rank up.
5. How long is employed (in days)? The older employees will be rank up.

**Important information**: employees can be given vacation whenever he reaches 365 days of work without license, and he needs to take vacation before completing 730 days of work. Every cycle between 365 and 730 days will grant him 30 days of vacation. That is the reason rule number 3 is so important.

I made a small table to work as an example:

The formula I have come up with is very simple, however I am not sure how to adjust it and also give the correct weights to every rule:

[image]

`=[@[Days of employment]]-IF([@[License within the last 12 days?]]="Yes",0.75,0.5)*([@[How long ago took vacation?]]-[@[How many days to vacation is due?]])*[@[Training Matrix Compliance]]/[@[How many days to vacation is due?]]`

Can you help me to check if this will work for the situation when employee are less than 90 days away from vacation due? Is there any input you can provide me to improve this formula given this set of rules?

I appreciate any help!

EDIT:
I did not notice the Vacation Due needs to rank up the individual the closer to 0. I also started working with Sumproduct in Excel to play with weighted average, as per the second image.

Thanks to Solar Mike I have included the analysis in column P to U.

@solar mike please check the scenario I tested and see the weight in column K. The closer the guys gets to 0 the earlier he needs to be in vacation.

[image]

Comment: Without the date of the last license then controlling 12 months is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

[image]

I compared the columns that have numbers of days to 1000, if any will exceed 1000 then you will have to cap that.

All the values were scaled to be 0 to 1. In column K 0 are replaced with 0.1, this may need to happen for other values but you can chase that.

The result in column N shows a result of who deserves the holiday the most. If you need to change the weighting between values then you can multiply by a weighting factor as needed.

I left the license as 1 or 0 - you can change that as needed.

Comment: Thanks for stepping up, Solar Mike!

I run a test here and I noticed that the weight given to Vacation Due needs to rank up the individual to the top the more it gets closer to 0. I think I did not made that clear in my original post.

But given your solution I could attribute a weight to this column in order to make it accordingly right?

I start playing with weighed average using sumproduct in Excel.

Note: I cannot post any image here, so I will make the adjustment in the original post with the second image being with your solution.

Comment: Given the fact that an employee could be with us for more than 18250 days dividing by 1000 could be a problem right?

Comment: So, why not use max() to find the duration of the longest working person and use that as the control? would still provide a number rating newest to oldest...